# Creating summary symbol in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, legend

A former coworker created a legend in ArcGIS Pro with this entry:

[image: Summary Symbol]

I thought there would be some setting to summarize the layer's symbology - something to indicate that features are shown in unique values but without listing every value.  I tried grouping, but that just gave me a single-color patch. And I've looked at other methods for symbology. I've also tried searching in help and Google - but I suspect I'm not thinking of the right terminology.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I heard back from my coworker and they don't recall making this.  So I have to assume it's not a setting and was something they created as a graphic as suggested by @Hornbydd in a comment.